# Regex not stopping at first space

Tags: regex

Trying to create a pattern that matches an opening bracket and gets everything between it and the next space it encounters. 
I thought `\[.*\s` would achieve that, but it gets everything from the first opening bracket on. How can I tell it to break at the next space?

Comment: In the end, I decided to go with (\[\S*\S) and it worked wonderfully in every situation I threw at it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
\[[^\s]*\s
```

The `.*` is a greedy, and will eat everything, including spaces, until the last whitespace character. If you replace it with `\S*` or `[^\s]*`, it will match only a chunk of zero or more characters other than whitespace.

Masking the opening bracket might be needed. If you negate the \s with ^\s, the expression should eat everything except spaces, and then a space, which means up to the first space.

Comment: I noticed this also matches the text "[ " How can I make the pattern ignore it if the first character following the open bracket is a space? So "[thisisvalid" but "[ thisisignored"

Comment: Then you wouldn't use `*`, which means 'any number of ... - including zero' but `+`, which might or might not need escaping, and means 'at least once'.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a reluctant qualifier:

```
[.*?\s
```

Or instead match on all non-space characters:

```
[\S*\s
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
\[[^ ]*
```

This matches the opening bracket (`\[`) and then everything except space (`[^ ]`) zero or more times (`*`).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `\[\S*(?=\s)`.

- `\[`: Match a `[` character.
- `\S*`: Match 0 or more non-space characters.
- `(?=\s)`: Match a space character, but don't include it in the pattern. This feature is called a *zero-width positive look-ahead assertion* and makes sure you pattern only matches if it is followed by a space, so it won't match at the end of line.

You might get away with `\[\S*\s` if you don't care about groups and want to include the final space, but you would have to clarify exactly which patterns need matching and which should not.

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace `.` with `[^\s]`, this would match "not space" instead of "anything" that `.` implies